# vim clang complete doesn't see some functions of opengl

Tags: c++, vim, autocomplete, clang

I have `vim` and `clang_complete` installed but for some reason when I try to auto complete it doesn't see some of OpenGL's functions, such as `glBindBuffer`, or `glEnableVertexAttribArray`. I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> to force the auto complete and it shows the function names and parameters, but it's just missing some of the functions.

Even with `glfw`, I try auto completing `GLFW_KEY_ESC` but it's not there, I don't know why, it just says `User defined completion (^U^N^P) Pattern not found`

Does anyone have a solution to this problem? It's very annoying because I use these functions a lot and need the auto complete.

Thanks.

EDIT: Also my include header files are this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glfw.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
```

I'm on `Arch Linux x64` by the way.

Comment: what does your `.clang_complete` file look like, and where are your gl headers located?

Comment: I don't have a .clang_complete file and my gl header files are located at /usr/include/GL. I also tried including #include <GL/gl.h> but that still didn't show glBindBuffer when I try to auto complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All right I found the answer. Because of clang_complete not being able to complete the arguments created by GLEW (because the functions are defined as #define FOO somefunction, and not defined as: #define FOO(arg1, arg2, arg3) someFunction(arg1, arg2, arg3))

To fix this, you have to add this option to your ~/.vimrc file.

```
let g:clang_complete_macros = 1
```

Now, you'll get function completion, but still no argument completion. So, you'll have to replace GLEW (sadly) with

```
#define GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glext.h>
```

This will finally complete the arguments, although, if there's an alternative to doing fixing this problem, I'd like to hear.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on zero57's answer.

You could add a clang_complete specific compile flag to define a macro for clang_complete

```
let g:clang_user_options = ' -DCLANG_COMPLETE_ONLY'
```

Then in your code you could use

```
#ifdef CLANG_COMPLETE_ONLY
    #define GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES
    #include <GL/gl.h>
    #include <GL/glext.h>
#else
    #include <GL/glew.h>
#endif
```

This isn't a perfect solution but clang_complete should now complete your parameters and when compiling you will be using glew. This worked for me with the YouCompleteMe (YCM) plugin so I assume it works with clang_complete.