# OpenGL Alternatives to GLEW that has arguments defined or a solution to it

Tags: c++, opengl, vim, autocomplete, arguments

so I posted [a question similar to this in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15260891/vim-clang-complete-doesnt-see-some-functions-of-opengl) but the solution seemed that it could be solved by a more simpler solution.

Basically, I'm using GLEW to load my OpenGL header files, etc, with no hassle, but since I'm using VIM and Clang_Complete to get argument completion, I'm stuck with having just the name completed and having no arguments actually shown. Since apparently the functions are defined as

```
#define FOO somefunction
```

and not defined as

```
#define FOO(arg1, arg2, arg3) somefunction(arg1, arg2, arg3)
```

My solution to this was adding an option in my ~/.vimrc file and having to completely remove GLEW and replace it with

```
#define GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glext.h>
```

So, I'm wondering if there's an alternative to GLEW that does what GLEW does, but actually shows the arguments, or if there's a way to solve this WITH using GLEW.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the interest of full disclosure, I wrote the following tool. I apologize if this reads like an advertisement.

You can use the [OpenGL Loader Generator](https://bitbucket.org/alfonse/glloadgen/wiki/Home). It's a tool that generates headers and source files for loading OpenGL functions. You specify which extensions and OpenGL versions you're interested in, and it only outputs the enums and functions for those versions. That's the primary feature of the tool: getting clean headers and source files that only contain the stuff you intend to use.

But the secondary feature is that it has different styles of generation. These styles define the specifics of how the output is generated.

The [standard "pointer_c" style](https://bitbucket.org/alfonse/glloadgen/wiki/Style_Pointer_C) generates code that looks a lot like GLEW, where the functions are `#define`s. That is actually *essential* in C, because you can't redefine globally accessible variables/function names. So you can't define a function pointer that has the same name as a non-pointer function. Such as `glVertex3f`; that name is already defined by the OpenGL library on some platforms, so you can't define a new version of it. You have to `#define` around it.

C++ on the other hand has namespaces. So in [the "pointer_cpp" style](https://bitbucket.org/alfonse/glloadgen/wiki/Style_Pointer_CPP), you get C++ headers and source that puts most of OpenGL in the `gl` namespace. This also means that the Pointer CPP style doesn't have to use #defines. So it doesn't. `gl::Vertex3f` is a function pointer with real argument types and names. Any decent code completion tool should be able to understand these.

[The "noload_cpp" style](https://bitbucket.org/alfonse/glloadgen/wiki/Style_No_Load_CPP) does the same thing. The difference is that there's no initialization function you have to call; you can call any function pointer and it will dynamically load that function if it hasn't been loaded already.

Spurred by this discussion, I have released a version of the tool that includes [the func_cpp style](https://bitbucket.org/alfonse/glloadgen/wiki/Style_Function_CPP). This uses inline functions to forward calls to the function pointers. This is directly using functions, so if it can't parse these, then there's no hope for your autocompletion tool.

Comment: So if I use this, and use pointer_cpp style or noload_cpp style I can get argument completion with clang_complete? Because basically what clang_complete uses is clang on the fly and generates completion just from using the compiler, which is why GLEW didn't want to show any argument completion because it wasn't defining any arguments.

Comment: @zero57: Well I can't *guarantee* it, as I've never used Clang for content completion. But those styles generate explicit function pointers, not `#define`s. So you've got a much better chance of it working. For what it's worth, VS2008 seems to work on it.

Comment: So I tried using OpenGL Loader Generator, but it just didn't work for me, I tried all styles but unfortunately it didn't want to autocomplete. I did like the idea though, however. It basically removes all deprecated features with ease.

Comment: @zero57: If it can't autocomplete based on function pointers, then there's no loader that's going to work. Well, I supposed you could *write* one. You could [modify the pointer_cpp style](https://bitbucket.org/alfonse/glloadgen/wiki/Style_Creation) so that the function pointers are in a different namespace, and the functions themselves are inline functions that forward parameters to the actual pointers. Or you could stop using a *crappy* autocomplete tool. Really, if it can't autocomplete based on function pointers, what good is it?

Comment: Sorry, I dislike using IDE's and I love using Vim, I'm forced to stick with this and having to define GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES if I want argument completion. Also, I'm not even using extensions, I'm using the original functions such as glBindBuffer and GLEW and your loader won't even give argument completions sadly. Only if I do this defining of the GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES and including those header files I could finally see arguments. I mean, it's fine if I have to live with this but I think there should be some way I could fix this other than having to switch away from VIM and using an IDE.

Comment: @zero57: I didn't say anything about using an IDE. I said to use a better autocomplete tool. If this "clang_complete" tool is so poor that it can't autocomplete a function pointer, odds are good that you're going to run into *other* circumstances it can't handle either. It's probably going to be a source of issues for you, so it's best to abandon it for something else. I highly doubt that "clang_complete" is the *only* autocompletion tool available for VIM.

Comment: @zero57: BTW, using that prototypes define is going to cause problems for you. It won't work on Windows; not for anything outside of GL 1.1. It may or may not work on MacOSX.

Comment: There are ctags and stuff but that only gets the functions with no arguments (at least in my experiences, I don't know if that changed or not but it clearly didn't work for me) I currently installed a new completion tool called YouCompleteMe and basically uses clang but does more than that, so I'll see if it'll work for me using your loader.

Comment: Okay, so all it does it show the function, nothing more. What I did was include the cpp and hpp created. I used "lua LoadGen.lua -style=pointer_cpp -spec=gl -version=3.3 -profile=core core_3_3" to generate my files. I didn't add any linker options or anything, I did exactly what I stated here and when I typed "gl::BindBuffer" all I saw was BindBuffer v PFNBINDBUFFER, nothing more, nothing less. No arguments in there. Am I doing anything wrong? And also, when you said defining prototypes not working on windows, etc, using your glLoadGen (and others such as GLEW) will work on other platforms?

Comment: @zero57: "*using your glLoadGen (and others such as GLEW) will work on other platforms*" Yes; that's what they're for. They [load OpenGL functions](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Loading_Library) on the platforms they support. Otherwise [you'd have to do this](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Load_OpenGL_Functions).

Comment: @zero57: "*when I typed "gl::BindBuffer" all I saw was BindBuffer v PFNBINDBUFFER, nothing more, nothing less*" That's not what's in the header. But then, I don't know anything about this autocompletion tool of yours. I assumed that the ecosystem around VIM was competitive with open-source IDEs and such. If it can't do autocompletion based on a function pointer, then it can't do it.

Comment: @zero57: I have made some updates to the tool, as explained at the bottom of the answer.

Comment: Hi, so I recently switched from clang_complete and youcompleteme to Eclipse's autocompleter. I'm using Eclim to integrate the completion into Vim and it is much better than these other two that I've been using. Although I can finally get argument completion from your tool using the pointer_cpp/func_cpp, the completion for example, glBindBuffer, only shows BindBuffer : void (*)(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int), is it possible if I could somehow get MORE information rather than just a bunch of unsigned ints? Because when I used the define prototypes I got more information.

Comment: @zero57: As I said in the answer, `func_cpp` doesn't expose function pointers. It exposes *inline function definitions*. I can't control what your autocompletion tools do. If your tool somehow sees these as function pointers that take basic types with no argument names, then that tool is really broken. And quite frankly, I spent more time accommodating crappy parsing tools that those tools deserve. *My* autocomplete tools work. At this point, I'm done making bad parsers happy.

Comment: I'm using Eclipse's auto complete which is much better than all of the ones I've used in the past, I've seen other people use it with GLEW fine somehow but right now when using GLEW it says that it couldn't even recognize the function for OpenGL. I don't think Eclipse's parser is bad, many people actually recommend it compared to Visual Studio. Also, I'm not talking about func_cpp, I'm also talking about pointer_cpp. Pointer_cpp now works with Eclipse's autocomplete. I actually saw no difference when using func_cpp. Anyways, thanks for trying to help. Maybe someone else can help.

Comment: Sorry for not getting your loader to work. I got func_cpp to work which actually gives me the whole argument completion! However, I was wondering if you can create a similar one, but instead of C++, can you do it with C? So it'd be like func_cpp, but it'd be func_c instead. I'd really like to use the C syntax because it will keep my code consistent instead of using namespaces with a few exceptions here and there. If it's impossible, then that's fine, but if it's possible and you have time, I'd appreciate if you could implement this into your work. Thanks again! (Nice tutorials btw)

Comment: @zero57: I can't do that and still use the expected names for functions. There is already a function called, for example, `glClear`. It's defined in the OpenGL library that you link to. So I can't define another one with the same name; doing so would be a linker error. I would have to call it something like `glFuncClear`. That's why it can only be done with C++, because `gl::Clear` isn't the same function as `glClear`. This is also why the C-based ones (as well as GLEW and other loaders) use `#define`s; so that they can call it `glClear` without linker problems.

Comment: I see, but isn't it possible to add arguments to #define's? Since for example, GLEW, it is defining functions by #define FOO somefunction and not #define FOO(arg1, arg2, arg3) someFunction(arg1, arg2, arg3). Anyways, I'll mark your solution as an answer, but if there's some way to get C syntax working, I'll be wanting to know how.

Comment: @zero57: I could do that, but there's also the fact that you aren't alone in using this tool. There are autocompletion tools that can parse through both `#define`s and function pointers. For them, the current state of GLEW and `pointer_c` work just fine. By using an argument-based `#define`, you thwart such tools.

Comment: Well, what such tools do you suggest other than Visual Studio because I'm on Linux and can't run Windows programs.

Comment: Hi, when I'm trying to compile my program, it says undefined reference to gl::BindBuffer, etc. I'm using "g++ src/main.cpp -glfw -lSOIL -lGL -lGLU" to compile my program. I'm using pointer_cpp and func_cpp style, and they both don't work. I haven't tried pointer_c or any others, but I think it won't work either. I also included the hpp file before any other files. Are you sure I don't have to link anything? Because usually I'd get these errors because of not linking the library, but you said that there's no need to link anything. And yes, I'm initializing it with gl::sys::LoadFunctions();

Comment: @zero57: Comments are not for questions. If you have a new question to ask, use the "Ask Question" button. Also, provide sufficient information, like the command-line you use to generate this code. Also, you know that you're supposed to include the generated source code in your project, right? Not as libraries, but as other `.cpp` files.

Comment: Sorry, the question can be found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15736923/opengl-loader-generator-undefined-reference-to-glbindbuffer-etc-opengl-funct

Comment: Sorry, I dont get it, but why to define macros of the same name as the functions that exist? That sounds stupid.

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution:

```
#ifdef USE_GLEW
    #include <GL/glew.h>
#else
    #warning "Not using GLEW"
    #define GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES
    #include <GL/gl.h>
    #include <GL/glext.h>
#endif
```

and...

```
// Initialize GLEW
#ifdef USE_GLEW
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    if (glewInit())
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLEW.\n");
    }
#endif
```

Then add `-DUSE_GLFW` flag to Makefile or CMakeList.txt. but **DO NOT** add to .ycm_extra_conf.py