# OpenGL Loader Generator undefined reference to gl::BindBuffer, etc (OpenGL Functions)

Tags: c++, opengl, reference, undefined

I have a problem when using [OpenGL Loader Generator](https://bitbucket.org/alfonse/glloadgen/wiki/Home), which when I try to compile my code, it doesn't work. It throws an error saying undefined reference to any opengl function I use, such as gl::BindBuffer, gl::GenBuffers, etc. I'm using pointer_cpp/func_cpp style.

My simple code that I'm using is

```
#include "gl_core_3_3.hpp"
#include <GL/glfw.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    glfwInit();
    glfwOpenWindow(1024, 768, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, GLFW_WINDOW);

    gl::exts::LoadTest didLoad = gl::sys::LoadFunctions();
    if(!didLoad) {
        glfwTerminate();
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When I compile that, it says undefined reference to gl::sys::LoadFunctions too. The command I'm using to compile is

```
g++ main.cpp -lglfw -lGL -lGLU
```

I'm on Arch Linux and using Vim with clang as my IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
g++ main.cpp -lglfw -lGL -lGLU
```

I don't see where you're including the generated source file. It's not a header-only loading system. It doesn't generate a library, but it does generate *source code*, which must be compiled.

Comment: I see, I changed #include "gl_core_3_3.hpp" to #include "gl_core_3_3.cpp" and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: @zero57: ***Don't include .cpp files!*** You *build* the .cpp file, just like you build your `main.cpp` file. You link them together. Just like you would for any program that has more than one source file. Have you never built a C++ program that has more than one source file before?

Comment: Oh sorry, and yes I have compiled a C++ program that has more than one source file, but I've never done anything like this before, English is not my first language. I've been confused with your sentence earlier. Thanks again though Nicol.